# Cannot archive Swift OSX app with Realm

Tags: swift, macos, realm

I have a Swift OS X app that uses RealmSwift (installed with CocoaPods 0.
39.0)

When I try to Archive it so that I can submit to the app store, I get 4 errors; all coming from RLMObject.h

> @interface RLMObject : RLMObjectBase

error: Duplicatie interface definition for class 'RLMObject'

The remaining three errors are all 'Poperty has a previous declaration'

> @property (nonatomic, readonly, nullable) RLMRealm *realm;
>
> @property (nonatomic, readonly) RLMObjectSchema *objectSchema;
>
> @property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isInvalidated) BOOL
>   invalidated;

The application builds fine and runs fine in development/debug mode.

Help

Answer (score 0):

updating realm to 0.98.4 fixed the problem for me.